# Can I somehow call logic from form_valid() in Django tests?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-testing

I am trying to test form for Post model creation in my simple forum application. The problem I am having is that after I try to save the form in tests I get an error `NOT NULL constraint failed: forum_web_post.user_id` because I am assigning the user in the `form_valid()` method in the view. The user is not passed via the form since the user that creates the post is the signed in user that sent the request.

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

user is imported form `django.contrib.auth.models` and Category model looks like this.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

in `views.py` after the user submits the form he is the redirected to his profile page

`views.py`

```
class PostCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'forum_web/post_edit.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = models.User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('forum:user_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.request.user.id}))
```

`forms.py`

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['category', 'title', 'text']
```

`tests.py`

```
    def test_post_form_create_should_pass(self):
        # this dict is in setUp() as well as the test_category but for simplicity I will include it in this method
        post_data = {
        'category': self.test_category.pk,
        'title': 'test_post',
        'text': 'test_post_text'
        }
        post_count = Post.objects.count()
        form = PostForm(data=self.post_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        form.save()
        self.assertEqual(post_count + 1, Post.objects.count())
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just testing the form. So it doesn't make sense to call a view function in your test. You should manually assign a user to the form's instance using `form.instance.user = ...` before saving the form in your test, since that's the way the form should be used.

In addition, you should test your view by actually logging in a user and posting the request to the `PostCreate` view. Here you're testing that the view correctly saves the form (and that your `form_valid()` method works correctly).

Note: `post.user = self.request.user` would be better than re-fetching the user from the database using the `id`. It's redundant.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! Even though I don't really know what the instance does. Would you mind explaining why it works now?

Comment: The form is a `ModelForm`, so `instance` is the actual `Post` instance that the form will save. When you do `post = form.save(commit=False)` in your view, you get the form's instance.